# Client Side encryption with S3 pre signed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, content-disposition

We have the following setup: Browser UI -> Our backend -> S3.

We want to do client side encryption (not using Amazon KMS) on the files stored in Amazon S3. Encryption will be done by our backend and the encrypted file will be stored in S3.

We also would like to use pre-signed URLs for streaming the files directly to the browser for larger files.

We are using Content-Disposition as attachment to let browser directly download the file.

I think our scenario will not work as the client side will not be able to decrypt the encrypted file.

Comment: You are correct. If your back-end is encrypting the files, then the back-end will need to also decrypt the files. Why are doing encryption in the back-end?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for the comment...do you mean to also encrypt from the front end while uploading ?...but is it advisable to encrypt/decrypt on the frontend as the key might get exposed in the browser..

Comment: Correct. Why are you wanting to perform the encryption in your own application, rather than within Amazon S3 itself? (There could be many valid reasons, I'm just wondering what has led you to this decision for your project.)

Comment: Yes...this is because we have a multi tenant application and we are using one bucket for all the customers. I understand that server side encryption with customer provided key is not possible on a single bucket. Hence exploring the option of client side encryption.

Comment: SSE-C is at an object-level. It will work fine in a single bucket, but the key would need to be provided whenever an object is requested. If your customers are accessing the content via your own app (as opposed to going to S3 directly), then using SSE-C would be no safer, since the security is determined by the application, not S3. What risk are you attempting to avoid by using SSE-C or back-end encryption? Do your customers have AWS credentials, or do they always access via your app?

Comment: Customers don't have AWS credentials. Its always managed through our App. We will explore if we can use SSE-C by providing the keys per request.  We might provide the pre-signed URLs to directly stream the content to browser for performance reasons.

Comment: SSE-C is not compatible with pre-signed URLs because the key is not provided. Your choice is either to use SSE-C due to a requirement for an unusually-high security posture and always upload/download via your app, or use normal Server-Side encryption (with or without KMS) to take full advantage of S3 while still encrypting data at-rest. Since the objects in Amazon S3 remain private by default, the security will be managed by your app. If you are a little paranoid, then use SSE-KMS since it will deny access even if the bucket is accidentally exposed publicly.